# Data repeat for eloquent query in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

```
$data = EmpData::leftJoin('states', 'states.id', 'emp_data.empState')
        ->leftJoin('districts', 'districts.id', 'emp_data.empDistrict')
        ->selectRaw('emp_data.*, states.name as stateName')
        ->selectRaw('emp_data.*, districts.name as districtName')
        ->paginate(30);
```

In my model 'EmpData' I contain state id and district id, and the 'state' & 'district' table includes the name of the state or district. so I use left join. Data fetch correctly, but it returns 4 times data, how can I fix it.

Comment: Do you have the models `EmpData`, `District` and `State` defined with both ways relationships? Then you can use Eloquent ORM syntax which is much more simpler.

Comment: Are there too many fields or too many records in what is returned?